# Precise geolocation incorrect across all internet browsers and websites in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, geolocation

For the last month or so, I've noticed that my device's precise location is frequently, if not always, incorrect on websites like google maps. This extends to google search results as well - at the moment, on Firefox, google thinks I'm in Vietnam (I'm actually in the US) and I'm getting search results in Vietnamese. I've tried different browsers and different websites like bing maps, and the results are the same. Here's what I know:

- I am not running a VPN
- My location is correct on my smartphone and in google maps on a different machine, both of which are on the same wifi network and logged in to my google account
- My IP location from sites like ipinfo.io is correct
- Google maps shows the correct area when first opening, before selecting "use precise location"
- Changing the value `geo.provider.network.url` from `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=%GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY%` to `https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=%MOZILLA_API_KEY%` as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/firefox#Geolocation_does_not_work) caused the location to change. Originally, google maps in Firefox would show me in Germany. After changing that value, it started to show me in Vietnam. Changing it back to the googleapis provider did not cause the location to change back to Germany from Vietnam. This also changed the results in Chromium which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, especially considering my next point
- Chromium now shows the correct location after I completely cleared all browsing data. It has only been a few minutes since discovering this and it is still working, both logged in to google and not logged in. I have not tried clearing my history and data in Firefox yet, and the location is still wrong there - even in a private browser.

Has anyone else had an issue like this? I suppose all I need to do right now is clear my data in Firefox, but I'm not convinced that there isn't a more interesting underlying issue. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.